# How to keep current activity run in background and return previous activity in android

Tags: android

I have MainActivity and CurrencyActivity.
At MainActivity, I call CurrencyActivity like this:

```
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(NewMainActivity.this, CurrencyActivity.class);
                        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

So, that I want is when I stay at CurrencyActivity, if user presses back button, the CurrencyActivity will run in background and return MainActivity.
I try use like this when user press back button :

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        //super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

But it doesn't return MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

In on back press function use code like this ... don't call finish()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(CurrencyActivity.this, NewMainActivity.class);             
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I use just like this but when I press Back and it call onDestroy?

Comment: onDestroy() will not call immediately. please read about Activity Lifecycle http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: The Activity is being recreated! When back button is clicked NewMainActivity is recreated hence amounting to multiple clicks to finally exit the app

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using: for API level 5

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // your code.
}
```

and for older then API 5 use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // your code
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: After I press Back it call onDestroy, So something wrong?

Comment: Your ActivityB will be destroyed once you press the back button and the application will get back to ActivityA. Then it will start from the onResume() method. So that's not a problem.

Comment: The problem is, want to keep ActivityB when return ActivityA, Now it just call onResume() when from ActivityA call the ActivityB. So I use moveTaskToBack() to keep it run in background but it still be destroy. Can you help me? @Prokash Sarkar

Comment: Keep track of the activity stack. Whenever you start a new activity with an intent you can specify an intent flag like FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT or FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP. You can use this to shuffle between the activities in your application. Have a look at the flags here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html